# Loading pretrained BERT model issue

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using Huggingface to further train a BERT model. I saved the model using two methods: step (1) Saving the entire model using this code: `model.save_pretrained(save_location)`, and step (2) save the state_dict of the model using this code: `torch.save(model.state_dict(),'model.pth')`
However, when I try to load this pretrained BERT model using the following code `bert_mask_lm = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('save_location')` for step (1) and `torch.load('model.pth')` for step (2), I am getting this following error in both steps:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _check_seekable(f)
    307     try:
--> 308         f.seek(f.tell())
    309         return True

AttributeError: 'torch._C.PyTorchFileReader' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Detailed stacktrace of step (1) is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _check_seekable(f)
    307     try:
--> 308         f.seek(f.tell())
    309         return True

AttributeError: 'torch._C.PyTorchFileReader' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1037             try:
-> 1038                 state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")
   1039             except Exception:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    593                     return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
--> 594                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    595         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moxing/framework/file/file_io_patch.py in _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    199 
--> 200     _check_seekable(f)
    201     f_should_read_directly = _should_read_directly(f)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _check_seekable(f)
    310     except (io.UnsupportedOperation, AttributeError) as e:
--> 311         raise_err_msg(["seek", "tell"], e)
    312     return False

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in raise_err_msg(patterns, e)
    303                                 + " try to load from it instead.")
--> 304                 raise type(e)(msg)
    305         raise e

AttributeError: 'torch._C.PyTorchFileReader' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/work/algo-FineTuningBert3/FineTuningBert3.py in <module>()
      1 #Model load checking
----> 2 loadded_model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('/cache/raw_model/')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1039             except Exception:
   1040                 raise OSError(
-> 1041                     f"Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' "
   1042                     f"at '{resolved_archive_file}'"
   1043                     "If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True. "

OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for '/cache/raw_model/' at '/cache/raw_model/pytorch_model.bin'If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

I am using the latest torch (1.7.1) and transformers (4.3.3) packages. I do not clearly understand what causes this error and how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is inside `/cache/raw_model/`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same thing. Turns out that this might be due to version indifference of both PyTorch and transformers. It has to be version-specific.

I used the following without downloading the latest bert-base-uncased model :

```
pip install torch==1.5.1
pip install transformers==3.0.2

MODEL_NAME = 'bert-base-uncased'
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
    MODEL_NAME
)
```

This will automatically download the pre-trained BERT model with respect to the suitable version of transformers
NOTE: I downloaded the vocab.txt explicitly from the official site separately and used that with BERT tokenizer class.